# Will achievement points be reset at the end of a ladder season?

Tags: starcraft-2

Greg asked this in another question of mine, so I'm reposting it here.

Will achievement points and so portraits be reset for the next ladder season?

Comment: I had no idea there was a "ladder season" (I'm a new player)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Blizzard hasn't mentioned anything about resetting achievement points at the end of the ladder season.  Additionally, no achievements are related to your ladder ranking so there is no reason to think they would get reset.

World of Warcraft has also had ladder seasons (and achievements associated with ladder ranking).  At no time have unrelated achievements been reset.  As a result, there is no reason to think they will at the end of the Starcraft season.

Comment: And to further that, not even the achievements for topping the ladder were removed - only the cosmetic in-game title (part of the rewards) was lost.